# how can I make static heatmap to openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, heatmap

I'm use openlayers 7.3.0 on Javascript
and This my source

```
async function monitoringRf(type){

    let params = makeParams();
    let response = await axios.post("/sm/monitoringRf.do", params);
    let heatRfData = response.data;
    
    heatRfData.forEach(function(value, index){
        const coordinates = transform([value.googlelon, value.googlelat], "EPSG:900913", "EPSG:900913");
        const feature = new Feature(new Point(coordinates));
        feature.set('weight', parseFloat(value.rf)/100); // rf 값을 가중치로 설정
        heatRfData[index].feature = feature;
    });
    
    // 히트맵 데이터로부터 히트맵 레이어 생성
    const heatmapLayer = new Heatmap({
        source: new VectorSource({
            features: heatRfData.map(data => data.feature),
        }),
        blur: 70, // 히트맵 블러 반경
        radius: 30, // 히트맵 포인트 반경
        opacity: 1.5, // 히트맵 불투명도
        valueField : 'rf',
    });
    // 맵에 히트맵 레이어 추가
    map.addLayer(heatmapLayer);
}
```

It is work well
but I want my HeatMap Layer not affect zoom event like [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-heatmap-static/)
how can I make static heatmap to use openlayers

Comment: radius and blur are defined in pixels, to be a static distance on the ground they will need to be based on inverse of the view resolution and change with the resolution https://codesandbox.io/s/heatmap-earthquakes-forked-3vs5qn?file=/main.js